# Improve js code to remove global variable and function

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, refactoring

I have a piece of js code which I would really like to improve but not sure how.
The working version below has a global variable and a separate function declaration which I think could be merged into a anonymous function (Code snipped below: Not working)

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

**Working version**:

```
var Data = {}; // would like to remove the global variable

function callBack() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://host/callBacks/script.js",
        //get and execute Script to process json data below
        dataType: "script"
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "http://host/data/json/",
        success: function(json) {
            Data = json; // Would like to just call the callback here
            callBack(Data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});


// Script which gets loaded from callBack
(function(Data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(Data);
    $.each(json, function(i, v) {
        alert(v);
    });
})(Data);
```

**Desired code: Not working**

```
// Error: Length is null or not an object. In jQuery script

var Data = {}; // Ideally would like to remove this from global scope if possible

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "http://host//data/json/",
        success: function(Data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://host/callBacks/script.js",
                dataType: "script"
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
// Error: Length is null or not an object. In jQuery script
```

UPDATE: As per adeneo answer:
Still need to the global Data = {}; because the returned immediately executing script takes in as parameter I suppose

```
var Data = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
    function doAjax() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://host/data/json/"
        });
    }

    var XHR = doAjax();
    XHR.done(function(data) {
        Data = data; // <--- If I remove this I get Error:'length' is not or not an object
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://host/callBacks/script.js",
            dataType: "script"
        });
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

Seems good enough though. Should probably mention that I'am testing this in IE 8. Constraint. Updated tags

Comment: this question would better fit http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "The working version below" "Code snipped below: Not working" o_O

Comment: I am not sure this is suitable for code review since I have a proposed my solution already but getting an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    function doAjax() { //put inside function
        return $.ajax({ //return deffered object
            type: "GET",
            url: "/data/json/" //X domain not supported
        });
    }

    var XHR = doAjax();  //do ajax call
    XHR.done(function(data) { // use deffered object
        var json = $.parseJSON(data); //why would you need to get an external script just to parse some JSON?
        $.each(json, function(i, v) {
            alert(v);
        });
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the global variable and related functions into a class and make an object from it inside the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here !
});
```

Comment: If I move var Data = {}; into the document.ready I get Data is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
(function () {

    var myData_andMethod = {
        data : {},
        method : function (data) { this.data = JSON.parse(data); }
    };

    $.ajax({success : (function (obj) {
            var callback = obj.method.bind(obj);
            return function (data) {
                callback(data);
            };
        }(myData_andMethod)) //, error : function... url:"".....
    });
    //attach events here.
}());
```

You've now got 0 global anythings.
Except now you've got to either make sure you DO something with the data, as soon as your callback fires (or it'll be gone forever, and you can never access it again), or you'll need to send it to some function which is in a known scope (global or part of your app or whatever...), or stick it in a var which **IS** publicly accessible, so that you ***can*** access the data after the closure is sealed, and all of the callbacks come back.

Even something as simple as sending the `myData_andMethod` object to some other function that stores the object elsewhere...